# Add new state on searchtool component

Tags: search

I want to add a new state to the article list filter on the search tool. The dropdown, has the states, Published, Unpublished, Archived, etc.

How do I add another state to the dropdown? Is there some file I have to change to achieve that?

I have found the file `filters.php` in the path `layouts/joomla/searchtools/default`.

But it only has an array with the filters, but where does theses values come from?

```
$data = $displayData;

// Load the form filters
$filters = $data['view']->filterForm->getGroup('filter');
?>
<?php if ($filters) : ?>
    <?php foreach ($filters as $fieldName => $field) : ?>
        <?php if ($fieldName != 'filter_search') : ?>
            <div class="js-stools-field-filter">
                <?php echo $field->input; ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Values are in coming from field type `status` in file `administrator/components/com_content/models/forms/filter_articles.xml`.

This field looks like this

```
<field
    name="published"
    type="status"
    label="COM_CONTENT_FILTER_PUBLISHED"
    description="COM_CONTENT_FILTER_PUBLISHED_DESC"
    onchange="this.form.submit();"
    >
    <option value="">JOPTION_SELECT_PUBLISHED</option>
</field>
```

If you add more `option` tags, it will show up. **But this is core file, so it's strongly not recommended to edit this.**

You should safely override this file, so if you update Joomla!, it won't be overwritten.

See discussion on [Joomla! forum: Overriding Form Field XML?](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=583380).

And [Form XML Override](http://extensions.joomla.org/profile/extension/miscellaneous/form-xml-override) extension should help.

Also, if you add new state, you should add it to edit view too. Edit view form XML is in same folder: `administrator/components/com_content/models/forms/article.xml`.

This state gets store in database field type `tinyint(3)`, so your `option` value should regard this.